# join table with itself to create more row

Tags: oracle

me has a table which has following data in TABLE1

[image]

me wanted to make sure all teh name has all "work type" available for all those dates only which is in teh data. Output should like TABLE2

[image]

me tried to put a query like

```
select t1.name,t1.date,mt.work_type,t1.minutes 
from table1 t1
right join (select distinct work_type from t1) mt on t1.work_type=mt.work_type
```

however it didn't work. Please halp

Comment: You misspelled `distinct`

Comment: You have tagged two RDBMS: Oracle and MySQL. Which one are you using?

Comment: Corrected the spelling & this is for oracle

Answer (score 0):

You need to join with a subquery that cross joins all the names, dates and work types.

```
SELECT mt.name, mt.date, mt.work_type, COALESCE(t1.minutes, 0) AS minutes
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.name, t1.date, t2.work_type
    FROM table1 AS t1
    CROSS JOIN table1 AS t2
) AS mt
LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1 
    ON t1.name = mt.name AND t1.date = mt.date AND t1.work_type = mt.work_type
ORDER BY mt.name, mt.date, mt.work_type
```

Note that in the subquery you have to specify the actual table name, not the alias from the main query.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3ed9989359ad0b053fca5a06a3e34bd)

Comment: This does not generate 18 rows; it only generate 10 [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2492a1123e2eac89bcffd317127a04f4).

Comment: Thanks. Actually it should be 18 rows. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use a partitioned outer join:

```sql
SELECT t.name,
       t."DATE",
       w.work_type,
       COALESCE(t.minutes, 0) AS minutes
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT work_type FROM table1) w
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t
       PARTITION BY (t.name, t."DATE")
       ON (w.work_type = t.work_type)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (name, "DATE", work_type, minutes) AS
SELECT 'a', DATE '2011-01-01', 'labor',   53 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', DATE '2011-01-01', 'private', 58 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', DATE '2011-01-01', 'other',   19 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', DATE '2011-01-02', 'labor',   31 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', DATE '2011-01-02', 'other',   24 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', DATE '2011-01-01', 'private', 19 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', DATE '2011-01-03', 'labor',   25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', DATE '2011-01-03', 'private', 50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', DATE '2011-01-01', 'private', 23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd', DATE '2011-01-01', 'other',   20 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NAME | DATE | WORK_TYPE | MINUTES |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | a | 01-JAN-11 | labor | 53 |
> | a | 01-JAN-11 | other | 19 |
> | a | 01-JAN-11 | private | 58 |
> | b | 01-JAN-11 | labor | 0 |
> | b | 01-JAN-11 | other | 0 |
> | b | 01-JAN-11 | private | 19 |
> | b | 02-JAN-11 | labor | 31 |
> | b | 02-JAN-11 | other | 24 |
> | b | 02-JAN-11 | private | 0 |
> | c | 01-JAN-11 | labor | 0 |
> | c | 01-JAN-11 | other | 0 |
> | c | 01-JAN-11 | private | 23 |
> | c | 03-JAN-11 | labor | 25 |
> | c | 03-JAN-11 | other | 0 |
> | c | 03-JAN-11 | private | 50 |
> | d | 01-JAN-11 | labor | 0 |
> | d | 01-JAN-11 | other | 20 |
> | d | 01-JAN-11 | private | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5f038b9b0a0854daad99d3952c17168a)*

---

In MySQL, you can use:

```sql
SELECT nd.name,
       nd.date,
       w.work_type,
       COALESCE(t.minutes, 0) AS minutes
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT work_type FROM table1) w
       CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT DISTINCT name, date FROM table1) nd
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t
       ON (t.name = nd.name AND t.date = nd.date AND t.work_type = w.work_type);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=883f232bd71b7a3cee02f4b54eebb8ad)*